# Why does C++ give you the option to have non new allocated objects?

Tags: java, c#, python, c++

In c++ you can make class objects that don't require to use the "new" keyword. Languages such as Java, (I believe a lot of other HIGHER level languages do too but for now I will focus on java) don't give you the option of making Class objects that don't require the keyword new. Why doesn't Java give you that option of making class objects non-new based and just limited to the scope of the function when it comes to class objects?

```
     Car mycar=Car();
     mycar.setName("an old name");
     Car mycar2=mycar;
     mycar2.setName("a new name");
     cout<<mycar.name;
```

In c++ this would result in "an old name".  But in languages such as Java you have to used the keyword new and both mycar and mycar2 share the same pointer and would print "a new name" and so you would have to create other separate objects with the keyword new to get deep copies.   My question was why doesn't java implement non-new based Class objects.  The ultimate question I had was what advantage does it have to make all class objects New in java.  I'm hoping this reworded the question to be more specific. I've not really used stack overflow before so I'm trying to learn the way this community works.

Comment: Why did this get a down vote. I feel it is a legitimate question?

Comment: I don't understand why you think C++ is the only language that doesn't require the use of the "new" keyword.  Python doesn't - in fact it doesn't have a reserved word `new`.  There is a `new` function in Python but its use is rare.  It's required only in a few special cases.

Comment: One language's keywords should not be confused or compared with another language's keywords, even if the keywords happen to be the same.

Comment: What I meant was that python passes class objects by reference and to my knowledge doesn't make non-pointer based class objects like you can do in C++

Comment: *passes class objects by reference* -- What does "passed by reference" mean?  Even that has multiple definitions, all depending on the language.

Comment: See above I reformated the question with an example I'm hoping this makes it clearer the point I'm trying to make

Comment: If you think C++ is the only language that allows creating objects with new (or some syntactic equivalent), then you need to do more homework.  There are actually several languages that require ONLY "non new allocated objects" (or syntactic equivalent).    In fact, historically, the earliest higher level languages did not support "new allocated objects" at all.    It's probably a sign of marketing spin associated with some modern languages (which portrays their approach as the only approach) that you believe "new allocated objects" is the primary approach.

Comment: I know that C++ isn't the only one that requires new.  Java for instance does.  I'm asking WHY in c++ you can make class objects that are essentially treated like primitives, when in more higher level classes you can't do that.

Comment: @WilliamJones Pascal doesn't require "new" to create classes (or records) and neither did Modula-2 (from what I remember).

Comment: @WilliamJones *But in any other language* -- Do you know how many computer languages there are?

Comment: C++ does not make deep copy by default... It doe exactly the same thing as c# with structs - shallow bitwise copy...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But don't worry my question was answered by people below, so if you can't figure it out it's okay

Comment: I've hopefully made it specific enough for everyone.  Please let me know if it needs more improvement.  The answers below essentially answered the question, but hopefully I've made the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of C++ is inherited from C and maintains the general principle that you don't pay for what you don't use.

Requiring all variables and/or objects to be referenced through a pointer and hence use `new` or `malloc` (in C) has a performance penalty. In C large structs were often referred to with pointers and allocated with `malloc()`. `new` accomplishes the same thing in C++ but also allows initialization of more complex objects. But, like C, objects can be instantiated on the stack and this can improve performance.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense,  so using new is not as efficient as just making variables without new generally?  And if I'm not mistaken in C++ using new uses memory from the heap,  while not using new uses memory from the stack right?

Comment: Right. It's great for manipulating small objects fast that you want to automatically go away when the scope is exited. And memory access tends to be quite fast with no extra overhead for grabbing and releasing heap memory. The one thing you have to watch out for coming from other languages is that you can't pass a reference or pointer out of scope to an object on the stack. One often sees newbies creating an array in local scope then returning a pointer to it. Legal in languages with hidden reference counters but not in C or C++.

Comment: @Pete Becker  Thanks for the edit. Very sloppy of me and potentially misleading since `alloc` is often a (dangerous) language extension that reserves space on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

The other languages listed use garbage collection to determine which objects are alive.

While you can do this with stack allocated objects, it is tricky as distant references to them can have to be remotely nulled when the stack moves.  This can happen at inopportune times.

In order to keep things easy, they force garbage collected objects to live where their lifetime can be extended to the longest outstanding reference.

C++ requires programmers to solve lifetime issues of remote references.  Once they place that requirement on a programmer, stack allocated objects with bounded lifetime are practical.

C++ screwups with lifetime lead to leaks and memory corruption.  The other languages still can suffer from leaks (as an unintended reference is kept around, possibly keeping alive unbounded amounts of resources).  File handle lifetimes and other "expensive" resources have to be manually managed in the other languages listed in a way similar to how C++ requires you to manage memory and object lifetimes.

Comment: Good points on other language garbage collection and its limits.

Answer (score 0):

This is because C++ is an hybrid programming language originally inheriting from C. C variable semantic is *by copy* (forget about pointers even if pointers are just copied to others as an `int`). You just define variables of a given type: `int i` and this *creates* an `int`, `struct S s;` *creates* an `S`. So semantic was naturally extended to object types: `C o` *creates* an object of type `C`. This then leaded to statically allocated object that are also automatically destroyed when leaving the scope. Almost the same happened for dynamically allocated object, but *the object way* using a `new` operator that let user control the initialization of the corresponding objects (new is basically almost a automatization of a call to malloc+init functions).

The main drawback of this is that **two** kinds of objects live at runtime: statically and dynamically allocated ones, and this could be a serious problem if you don't take care about.

Among advantages, you can take an existing C program, slightly adapt it to change the type of the variables from primitives ones to objects ones and let it simply work. This let C-like programmers switch slightly from procedural to object-oriented paradigm, etc.

Remember that the general guideline for C++ designers is: «if a design choice exists, don't choose, implement both and let programmer choose.»

Now designers of primarily object oriented languages who don't take care about compatibility are free to design something more coherent that is not the source of potential problems. Java designers (for example) did many many choices (no operator overloading, dynamic binding, garbage collection, etc).